# i want to create a template that some when will appear and after some thing will disappear how can i hide it?

Tags: javascript, html

i dont know how after i showed my template i can to hide it one more time

```js
function show() {
    var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
    var clon = temp.content.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(clon);
}
```

```html
<template class="tem">
        <p class="tem">
            enter your name:
            <br>
            <input type="text">
            <br>
            enter your password
            <br>
            <input type="password">
        </p>
    </template>
    <button onclick="show()" class="temp">unp</button>
```

Comment: "after some thing" ...after what thing, exactly? We can't guess. But probably either you need to handle a different event (e.g. clicking on another button, perhaps), or a timer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly but I guess you meant you want to toggle between removing or showing the content of the template, if so, here is the code :

```js
function toggle() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("tem").length == 1) {
       var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
       var clon = temp.content.cloneNode(true);
       document.body.appendChild(clon);
    } else {
      var el = document.getElementsByClassName("tem")[1];
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }
}
```

```html
<template class="tem">
        <p class="tem">
            enter your name:
            <br>
            <input type="text">
            <br>
            enter your password
            <br>
            <input type="password">
        </p>
    </template>
    <button onclick="toggle()" class="temp">unp</button>
```